# Simple explicit example of higher Eilenberg-MacLane space

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, classifying-spaces, eilenberg-maclane-spaces

Given an Abelian group $G$ and a positive integer $n$, the Eilenberg-MacLane space $K(G,n)$ is a topological space such that $\pi_n(K(G,n))=G$, while $\pi_m(K(G,n))=0$ if $m\neq n$. For $n=1$ this coincides with the classifying space $BG$, and for many $G$ (for instance $U(1), \mathbb{Z}$ and cyclic groups) this has simple geometric realizations (for instance $K(U(1),1)=\mathbb{CP}^{\infty}$ while for $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is an infinite dimensional Lens space).

Is there some case in which $K(G,n)$, $n>1$ has a similarly simple geometric realization?

Side question: it is often written $K(G,n)=B^nG$, where $B^nG=B(B^{n-1}G)$ but I never understood this notation, since I know what is $B(\text{something})$ is $\text{something}$ is a group, but not in other cases. Could someone explain this to me?

Comment: $K(G,n)$ is at least a group object in the category of homotopy types. The multiplication map $m\colon G\times G\to G$ induces a map $m\colon K(G\times G,n)=K(G,n)\times K(G,n)\to K(G,n)$.

Comment: A related question of mine with a few more examples: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2348307

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provided $G$ is an $E_n$ space, then $BG$, $B^2G$, $\dots$, $B^{n-1}G$ are topological groups, so $B^nG = B(B^{n-1}G)$ is defined, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1729402/39599). Moreover, if $G$ is a discrete abelian group, then $B^nG$ is defined for all $n$ and it is a $K(G, n)$, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2120143/39599). Note, if $G$ is not equipped with the discrete topology, then $B^nG$ need not be a $K(G, n)$. For example, a model for $BU(1)$ is $\mathbb{CP}^{\infty}$ which is not a $K(U(1), 1)$ as you claimed. Instead, we have a fibration $U(1) \to EU(1) \to BU(1)$ from which it follows that $\pi_k(BU(1)) \cong \pi_{k-1}(U(1))$, so $BU(1)$ is in fact a $K(\mathbb{Z}, 2)$. Another way to see this is that $U(1)$ itself is a model for $B\mathbb{Z}$, so $BU(1) = B^2\mathbb{Z}$.

As for explicit models of $K(G, n)$ for $n > 1$, aside from $\mathbb{CP}^{\infty}$, these are hard to come by. One surprising one is $Top/PL$ which is a $K(\mathbb{Z}_2, 3)$ which gives rise to the [Kirby-Siebenmann invariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirby%E2%80%93Siebenmann_class). Also see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2851921/39599).

Comment: Could you maybe explain how the group structure on $G$ induces a group structure on $BG$? (My definition of $BG$ is $EG/G$, where $EG$ is any contractible space with an action of $G$ without fixed points)

Comment: If $G$ has an $E_2$ structure, I don't know how to describe the group structure on $BG$ explicitly. Part of the problem is that $BG$ is only defined up to homotopy. Maybe someone more knowledgeable about these things could provide an answer. I suggest asking a new question if you are interested.