# Classifying Spaces of Matrix Lie Groups

Tags: algebraic-topology, lie-groups, k-theory, classifying-spaces, eilenberg-maclane-spaces

I’m currently studying the classifying spaces of some of the matrix Lie groups. I’ve come across a post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2850108/classifying-space-bsun) that describes the classifying spaces for $SO(n)$, $SU(n)$, $GL(n)$, and $Sp(n)$. I’ve also seen computations for these in other places.

I'm interested in the classifying space for $SL(n,\mathbb{Z})$. As discussed in the comments, this is the same as the Eilenberg-MacLane space $K(SL(n,\mathbb{Z}),1)$. There is a general construction of these spaces given in Hatcher's algebraic topology. However, I can't determine from this if $K(SL(n,\mathbb{Z}),1)$ is some common space. Is there a different method that determines $K(SL(n,\mathbb{Z}),1)$?

Comment: $SL(n, \mathbb{R})$ has $SO(n)$ as a maximal compact subgroup, so any model for $BSO(n)$ is a model for $BSL(n, \mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Great, thank you! Is $BSL(n,\mathbb{Z})$ less understood?

Comment: $SL(n, \mathbb{Z})$ is a discrete group, so a connected topological space $X$ is a model for $BSL(n, \mathbb{Z})$ if $\pi_1(X) = SL(n, \mathbb{Z})$ and all higher homotopy groups vanish. I don't know of any explicit examples of such spaces.

Comment: I see. You’re saying that we could look for the Eilenberg-MacLane space $K(SL(n,\mathbb{Z}),1)$.

Comment: Yes, exactly. If $G$ is a discrete topological group, then $BG = K(G, 1)$.

Comment: It may be possible, but I don't see how.

Comment: It is "almost" the quotient $SL(n,{\mathbb Z})\backslash SL(n,{\mathbb R})/SO(n)$, except the action of $SL(n,{\mathbb Z})$ on the symmetric space $SL(n,{\mathbb R})/SO(n)$ is not free. But there is an easy way to fix this using, for instance, the fact that $SL(n,{\mathbb Z})$ contains a finite index torsion-free subgroup.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Could you expand on how we can use that $SL(n,\mathbb{Z})$ has a finite index torsion-free subgroup to resolve the issue that the action is not free?

Comment: Do you know what Borel construction is?

Comment: I know a little bit about it. In this case, it seems like you are wanting to use the fact that if X is a topological space that G acts freely upon, then $(X\times EG)/G$ is homotopic to $X/G$, but I can’t see how to use that here.

Comment: You mention that you cannot determine "if $K(SL(n,\mathbb Z),1)$ is some common space". That all depends on what is "common". In homotopy theory there is a general, very well understood, "common" construction of the Eilenberg-Maclane space $K(G,1)$ associated to any discrete group. In a few very special cases, $K(G,1)$ is *homotopy equivalent* to a space that was "common" before the emergence of the work of Eilenberg-and Maclane: $K(\mathbb Z,1)$ is homotopy equivalent to the circle; $K(\mathbb Z^n,1)$ is homotopy equivalent to the $n$-dimensional torus $(S^1)^n$; and a few others.

Comment: @LeeMosher I was hoping that $K(SL(n,\mathbb{Z}),1)$ would be homotopic to a space that was "common" before Eilenberg and MacLane, just like $K(\mathbb{Z}^n,1)$ is homotopic to $(S^1)^n$. What you mentioned is a good point though, not having such a homotopy is what makes the Eilenberg-MacLane construction useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an answer of sorts. The quotient $X=SL(n,{\mathbb R})/SO(n)$ is a symmetric space of noncompact type, hence, a contractible manifold. The group $\Gamma=SL(n,{\mathbb Z})$ acts on $X$ properly discontinuously but not freely (via the left multiplication of cosets): Stabilizers of points are finite. The group $\Gamma$ contains a torsion-free subgroup $\Gamma_0$ of finite index, the kernel of the natural projection
$$
\Gamma\to SL(n,{\mathbb Z}/3). 
$$
(I think, this is due to I.Schur.) Hence, $\Gamma_0\backslash X$ is a classifying space for $\Gamma_0$. To get one for $\Gamma$ itself one can do the following. Take the classifying space for the finite group $SL(n,{\mathbb Z}/3)$, it is the quotient $SL(n,{\mathbb Z}/3)\backslash Y$, where $Y$ is a contractible CW complex. (This should be treated as a black box.) You get a free proper action of $\Gamma$ on $X\times Y$ where the group $\Gamma$ acts on $X$ as above and acts on $Y$ via the homomorphism $\Gamma\to SL(n,{\mathbb Z}/3)$. Then the quotient
$$
\Gamma\backslash (X\times Y)
$$
is a classifying space for $\Gamma$. What is it good for, I do not know.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I suppose that this shifts the question to understanding the classifying space of $SL(n,\mathbb{Z}/3)$.

Comment: @slowspider: The real question is: what would you like to know about this classifying space? There are explicit constructions (especially if the group is finite), what else do you need? Compute cohomology groups? What else?

Comment: Like my response to Lee said, I was wondering if $K(SL(n,\mathbb{Z}),1)$ is homotopic to a space that was "common" before Eilenberg and MacLane, just like $K(\mathbb{Z}_n,1)$ is homotopic to $(S^1)^n$. That doesn't appear to be the case, so what you have is great!